# Outlook warning when Python script runs

Tags: python-2.7, outlook

I'm using Python to download attachments from Outlook.

Outlook is displaying below warning.
[image: Outlook Warning]

I tried to enable macros in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the security prompt you need to either

1. get up-to-date antivirus app.
2. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi).
3. Get a library (such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) - I am its author) that bypasses the security prompt by using Extended MAPI.

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for more details.